# Best GUI Framework for Ruby. Not Shoes

Tags: ruby, user-interface, frameworks

I am trying to settle on a GUI framework for Ruby and I have yet to decide which one I prefer and would like some input. I mainly want to pick the framework with the most support and community involvement. I have shied away from Shoes because the site is down and because I would like some challenge and understanding of what is going on behind the scenes.

I took a look at this post (which is a bit dated so I was hoping for some modern input):
[Best Ruby GUI Framework](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/48681)

The two frameworks I have looked at are [FXRuby](http://www.fxruby.org/) and [Ruby-GTK2](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/) and I was hoping someone could give some pros and cons to these frameworks or perhaps a recommendation of a GUI framework for Ruby.

Oh and if you do think Shoes is the way to go, please mention that as well.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I decided to settle on Ruby-GNOME2. Seemed to have a lot of the customizable aspects I was looking at without being overly complex. Here's the link in case anyone else is considering making GUIs in Ruby.

[Ruby-GNOME2](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/)

Comment: If you want to improve this question for future searchers you might add into the question statement what features specifically you were looking for (sufficient/necessary) and conditions that would have been deal breakers for you.

Answer (score 5):

Shoes' site isn't 'down' it's been removed (and [now](http://groups.google.com/group/shoooes/browse_thread/thread/9f323299368d700) [relocated](http://shoes.heroku.com/)) by [_why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Why_the_lucky_stiff) who [left the community](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9c5u4/this_is_a_sad_day_why_disappears/) [abruptly](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=773106) in August 2009.

So, my answer: [Shoes](http://github.com/whymirror/shoes) :)

Comment: Posted this initially in the wrong questions:
Is there any way to 'deploy' a Shoes application. It seems that if you decide to use the Shoes framework you are bound to using Shoes.run and then selecting a .rb file to use. I would like to have a way to have a standalone GUI application that could just be run from the command line

Comment: you can deploy shoes apps as standalone .exe files. The program that does this is started from the command line with: "shoes -p"

Comment: yeah you'll love those ruby shoes as you skip down the yellow brick lane.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Mac OS, try MacRuby. It isn't a GUI toolkit, per se, but it essentially lets you use all of Cocoa from Ruby (it is built on top of CoreFoundation and the Objective-C Runtime). MacRuby is your best bet, if you're willing to develop apps that will only work on Mac OS X.

Comment: Macs really what I am aiming to develop for...mainly Linux and perhaps Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Swing or SWT.

Yes, I know, it's a *really* sad state of affairs if any of those two is the best answer to any problem, but that's the way it is.

Comment: I agree, I found wx ruby really unstable and incomplete and fx overly complex. there are a bunch of java based frameworks that seem ok.

Comment: Is there any way to 'deploy' a Shoes application. It seems that if you decide to use the Shoes framework you are bound to using Shoes.run and then selecting a .rb file to use. I would like to have a way to have a standalone GUI application that could just be run from the command line.

Comment: Shoes 3 includes a packager that will generate .exe files for windows as well as binaries for mac and linux.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might find [RuGUI](http://rugui.org/) interesting. From the website:

> RuGUI is a framework which aims to help building desktop applications. RuGUI was mostly inspired by the Ruby on Rails framework, taking most of its features from it.

There's also support for RSpec and Test:Unit

It started with a focus on Gtk, but it looks like support for Qt is added by now. It lacks structured documentation, but [these](http://blog.rugui.org/2009/01/hello-rugui/) two [blogposts](http://blog.rugui.org/2009/04/getting-your-feet-wet-with-rugui/) will help you a lot.

The developers are eager to improve the framework.

Comment: Site appears to be down.

Answer (score 0):

[wxRuby](http://www.wxruby.org) has bindings to wxWidgets, and runs on linux, mac, windows. it uses native windowing when possible.

cute simple dsl's in proccess.

Comment: The link is broken.